# Differential equation for quantity of salt at a certain time

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Hi I'm having a lot of trouble with the following problem, I tried using the equation dQ/dt = 3Q/2006-3t but it doesn't work.

> A tank contains 90 kg of salt and 2000 L of water. Pure water enters a tank at the rate 6 L/min. The solution is mixed and drains from the tank at the rate 3 L/min. How much salt is left in the tank after 5 hours.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $s(t)$  be the amount of salt in the tank at the time $t$. Then
$$\begin{cases}
s'(t)=-\underbrace{(6-3) \text{ L/min}\cdot \frac{s(t)\text{ kg}}{2000 \text{ L}+(6-3) \text{ L/min}\cdot t \text{ min}}}_{\text{rate that salt leaves the tank in kg/min}}\\
s(0)=90 \text{ kg}
\end{cases}$$
Now solve the Cauchy problem and find $s(5\cdot 60)$.

Comment: after integrating factors, is s(t)= -3/(2000+3t) * s^2/2 + C ?

Comment: @Alex.G What is Q?

Comment: sorry about that, see the edit in my comment

Comment: BTW, have you the numerical answer of this exercise?

Comment: No I don't sadly. But I use webworks for my class so if I put in the right answer it will tell me. Also shouldn't s(0) = 90 ? If so, does that change the s(t) equation you obtained? @RobertZ

Comment: Yes, my fault. Separate the variables and integrate both parts. You should find $()=180000/(2000+3) $

Comment: Thank you Robert! @RobertZ

Answer (score 1):

Let the tank contain $V$ litres of water and $S$ kg of salt at time $t$.

Then $$V=2000+3t,\frac{dS}{dt}=-\frac{3}{V}S.$$

Can you finish it off now?